# How to log within a stored procedure that is encapsulated within a transaction

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transactions, mysql-5.5

**Short version:**
If there is a started transaction which will be possibly rolled back, how is it possible to log something into a log table?
(The rollback of the transaction would also rollback the log entries which is the problem here.)

**Long version:**

I have a stored procedure, let us call it `sp_A` which calls other stored procedures, let us call them `sp_B` and `sp_C`. For the sake of consistency an `XA TRANSATCION` is started within `sp_A`. What I actually want to do is to log if the execution of `sp_B` or `sp_C` fails and if so, which were the arguments passed to the failing stored procedure.
But as `sp_B` and `sp_C` do some inserts in some tables, I need to do a `XA ROLLBACK` if `sp_B` or `sp_C` fails.

So my question is: **How can I log into a table while I am within a transaction
(or how to execute an insert statement outside of the transaction scope)?**

To give you a little example of what I want to do (I've simplyfied the code and renamed most of the parameters/variables used to focus on the problem, I would never dream of using parameter names like `a`, `b` or `c` ;-) ):

The stored procedure `sp_A` looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_A`
(
  IN a INT,
  IN b VARCHAR(64),
  OUT c INT
)
sp_label:BEGIN
  DECLARE l_errorMessage TEXT;
  DECLARE l_spSuccess INT;
  DECLARE l_errorOccured INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION BEGIN
    SET l_errorOccured = 1;
  END;

  XA START 'sp_A';

  CALL sp_B(a, b, l_spSuccess);

  IF l_errorOccured OR (l_spSuccessResult < 0) THEN
    XA END 'sp_A';
    XA ROLLBACK 'sp_A';
    SET c = -1;
    SET l_errorMessage = CONCAT('CALL sp_B(', a, ', ', b, ', l_spSuccess);');
    CALL sp_Log(l_errorMessage);
    LEAVE sp_label;
  END IF;

  CALL sp_C(a, b, l_spSuccess);

  IF l_errorOccured OR (l_spSuccessResult < 0) THEN
    XA END 'sp_A';
    XA ROLLBACK 'sp_A';
    SET c = -2;
    SET l_errorMessage = CONCAT('CALL sp_C(', a, ', ', b, ', l_spSuccess);');
    CALL sp_Log(l_errorMessage);
    LEAVE sp_label;
  END IF;

  XA END 'sp_A';
  XA COMMIT 'sp_A';
  SET c = 1;
END;
```

The stored procedure `sp_B` looks like this (`sp_C` looks similar):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_B`
(
  IN a INT,
  IN b VARCHAR(64),
  OUT c INT
)
sp_label:BEGIN
  DECLARE l_errorMessage TEXT;
  DECLARE l_spSuccess INT;
  DECLARE l_errorOccured INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION BEGIN
    SET l_errorOccured = 1;
  END;

  INSERT INTO `someTable` (`a`, `b`) VALUES (a, b);

  IF l_errorOccured THEN
    SET c = -1;
    SET l_errorMessage = CONCAT('INSERT INTO `someTable` (`a`, `b`) VALUES (', a, ', ', b, ');');
    CALL sp_Log(l_errorMessage);
    LEAVE sp_label;
  END IF;

  SET c = 1;
END;
```

`sp_Log` just inserts data into a table which I want to use as my `logging table`.

So actually the logging within `sp_A` works just fine (because the call to `sp_Log` is outside a transaction) but the logging within `sp_B` or `sp_C` won't work because by rolling back the transaction started in `sp_A`, the inserts done by the call of `sp_Log` within `sp_B` or `sp_C` are reverted of course.

(I have simplified the example, in `sp_B` and `sp_C`. There is more going on than just one simple insert statement and just to have more fun, there are transactions started and commited/rolled back within `sp_B` and `sp_C` as well.)

I would appreciate any hints you could give me.
Thanks!

Comment: Whoever voted down... Please give me details why you did so, so that I can improve the question...

Comment: I tried wrapping log commands in another transaction (my "main" is equivalent to your "sp_a"). Something like:
        IF `_rollback` THEN
      XA END "main";
      XA PREPARE "main";
      XA ROLLBACK "main";
      XA START "log";
      INSERT INTO logtable(`message`) VALUES ('Rolled back');
             XA END "log";
             XA COMMIT "log" ONE PHASE;
             LEAVE this_procedure;
        END IF;
Unfortunately, I'm facing additional unrelated problems, therefore I cannot declare my solution as working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem's that one viable way of solving this issue is using a table engine that does not support transactions. In this case changing the table engine of the log tables from `InnoDB` to `MyISAM` solved the problem.